# Firebase onDisconnect every 20 minutes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running this code in background.html for a chrome extension, to monitor the online state of the extension:

```
var amOnline = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
amOnline.on('value', function(snap) {
        if (snap.val() === true ) {               
            console.log("connected")               
        }
        else {
            console.log("disconnected")
        }
    });
```

when I look at the console, I see this:
It looks like connect/disconnect intervals for every 20 minutes (+/-)

```
07:57:06.597 background.js:75 connected
08:44:43.261 background.js:99 disconnected
08:44:44.606 background.js:75 connected
09:05:19.879 background.js:99 disconnected
09:05:21.999 background.js:75 connected
09:34:57.091 background.js:99 disconnected
09:34:57.907 background.js:75 connected
09:54:49.555 background.js:99 disconnected
09:54:50.279 background.js:75 connected
10:35:25.933 background.js:99 disconnected
10:35:27.604 background.js:75 connected
10:55:16.865 background.js:99 disconnected
```

Why is firebase doing this, and what can I do to prevent it?
I am saving the sessions of the online status. These are -anonymous- users, so no auth / login state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the web api of firebase. But On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

This might give you some insight why is it happening in web.